# Auto check processor AES-NI support before installation

Tags: linux, installation

I have one interesting question. I have custom distribution of CentOS Linux 6.3. The installed system needs CPU support for AES-NI for all services to work properly.

Can I add a check for AES support during the installation? I'm using Anaconda, but am willing to consider other ways to do it as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [How to check that AES-NI is supported by my CPU?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/14077/20805)

Comment: Thanks, I know about this way, but information in /proc/cpuinfo becomes available after OS installation complete only. I need get this information before OS installation. I want that installer check this CPU options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would require a [kickstart script](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/ch-kickstart2.html) to be used. Fortunately the kickstart script need only be [trivial](https://access.redhat.com/knowledge/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/s1-kickstart2-preinstallconfig.html). You may use this alone (for an otherwise normal interactive installation) or as part of an existing kickstart script.

```
%pre --erroronfail
#!/bin/sh
grep -q aes /proc/cpuinfo || exit 1
%end
```

If the CPU doesn't [show this feature](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/14077/20805), the script will error exit and [the installation will stop](https://serverfault.com/a/446441/126632). Note that while this feature works, it is officially undocumented and not supported by Red Hat. (Not that it matters if you use CentOS...)

Comment: Thanks! It's works, but I have new problem now. I tried to execute this command: grep -q aes /proc/cpuinfo || echo "Don't enable AES-NI!" && sleep 15 && exit 1. And system stop installation but don't write any messages to console.